# Case based proof using nat comparisons in COQ

Tags: coq

I am currently trying to prove something like this:

```
1 subgoals
a : nat
IHa : {x : nat | something_with a x}
______________________________________(1/1)
{x : nat | something_with (S a) x}
```

The problem is that in order to provide a value for the `x` variable and prove that the set is not empty, I need to compare `x` and `S a` and provide values accordingly since the `x` that works with `a` and `S a` could be different if `x` is greater or equal than `a`.

Any clues on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using the case tactic to create two subgoals, one to be solved given S a <= x and the other given x < S a ?

```
case IHa.
intro x.
intro H.
case (le_lt_dec (S a) x).
```

Or you could do

```
destruct IHa.
case (le_lt_dec (S a) x).
```

destruct applies the intros tactic automatically.

Comment: This is returning an error: Error: The reference x was not found in the current environment.

Comment: You need to destruct hypothesis IHa first and introduce x.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I did add a destruct H and it worked. Doing intro H did not do the trick, though. Edit your answer accordingly and I will accept it. THanks !

Comment: If you use destruct, there is no need for intro H because it is done automatically.  I edited my answer to show how to do it using destruct.